# Terrain generation with height map

Tags: python

I have python program that generates heightmap (matrix). Which way to generate landscape would be better? I'm new to blender, so I don't know where to start

Comment: Is it a gridlike matrix, a rectangle with rows and columns?

Comment: @Leander yes, it's gridlike  square matrix whose values are heights

Comment: I'm interested on the way you generated that landscape, care to elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of achieving this would be to save the matrix as an `.exr` image texture (for instance using the `imageio` package and its `imwrite()` function).

You can then create a plane and add a `Subdivision Surface` modifier (on the wrench in the menu) changing from Catmull-Clark to Simple, and then add a `Displace` modifier.

On the `Displace` modifier, click `New` to create a new texture and then go to the texture menu (a square like a chess board).

There you can open your `.exr` image.

Now if you go back to the modifiers menu, as you increase the viewport subdivisions in the `Subdiv` modifier you should see how the plane starts to resemble your image.

If there's interest on this I'll add more details and screenshots :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already done it but forgot about the question.